# Python eggs - sometimes inflated, sometimes not

Tags: python, egg

I'm running fedora 32 bit on one machine and have installed several eggs using easy_install.

I've installed the same eggs using easy_install on a 64-bit centos 5 machine. The site-packages directories are different - on my fedora machine, some of the eggs have been inflated so there are directories ending .egg-info as well as the main code directories. On Centos there are no .egg-info directories. Why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package can specify itself using the zip_safe flag inside its setup.py file if it should be unarchived or not. In addition most installers like 'easy_install' provide options to control the unpacking explicitly (e.g. easy_install --zip-ok ...)...so it may depend on how the packages are installed under Fedora oder CentOS.